# Figure caption with long description, but description not in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I try to have longer descriptions for my figures after the caption. So far, I found a solution to do that. However, the longer description is also displayed in the list of figures, which I don't want. In the list of figures, only the short caption should appear.

Here is my minimum example, I hope someone can help:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1}\newline\small#2}}

\begin{document}
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \mycaption{Optimizing detection algorithm displayed as an decision tree.}{Longer description. $t_i$ is blabla, $l_i$ is blabla and so on.}
    \centering
    \rule{100mm}{100mm}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I added a picture of the resulting document and marked what needs to be gone.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`\caption[ToC entry]{Float caption which will be different from ToC entry}`

Comment: So, I edited my new command to `\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1}\newline\small#2}}` which solved the problem. Thank you.